# Delete all users with Editor role and their content mysql

Tags: users, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a Wordpress site with thousands of editors. I cant delete them from the WP dashboard as its to slow.

I need a query to delete all the editor users and their posts from PhpMyAdmin?

Thanks

Comment: Single site, or Multisite network?

Comment: Thanks, single site!

Answer (score 0):

It's a three step process.

1. First, get a list of Editors using [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/).
2. Get a list of each user's posts using [`get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and delete them using [`wp_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/).
3. Lastly, delete the user itself using [`wp_delete_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_user/).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: So what would I type in the PhpMyadmin query tool?

Comment: You don't. This is a php process and you'll need to code them. The SQL quarries will be handled by WordPress itself.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help